# How to use NOT IN and joins in AciveRecord/Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following schema:

```
create_table "ad_groups", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
create_table "ad_placements", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "advertisement_id"
  t.integer  "ad_group_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
  t.index ["ad_group_id"], name: "index_ad_placements_on_ad_group_id", using: :btree
  t.index ["advertisement_id"], name: "index_ad_placements_on_advertisement_id", using: :btree
end
create_table "advertisements", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "image"
  t.string   "link"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  t.date     "expiry_date"
  t.integer  "company_id"
  t.index ["company_id"], name: "index_advertisements_on_company_id", using: :btree
end
create_table "companies", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false

end
create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "company_id"
  t.string   "group_type"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.index ["company_id"], name: "index_groups_on_company_id", using: :btree
end
```

I want to get all the groups which are public or private and not a part of a particular ad group called “MyAds” using AciveRecord. I have managed to get the list using the following query but it looks ugly and I’m sure there is a better way to do it. Can anyone please help?

```
 Group.where("group_type = 'Public'").or(Group.where("group_type = 'Private'")).where("groups.id NOT IN (SELECT groups.id FROM advertisements INNER JOIN ad_placements ON advertisements.id = ad_placements.advertisement_id INNER JOIN ad_groups ON ad_placements.ad_group_id = ad_groups.id INNER JOIN groups on groups.company_id = advertisements.company_id WHERE ad_groups.name = 'MyAds')")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OR` condition can be combined into a single `IN` condition if you pass 'Public' and 'Private' in an array.  And you might want to check out [`merge`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#merging-of-scopes) to let Rails manage the join conditions.  Here's a possible alternative:

```
my_ad_groups = Group.joins(company: { advertisements: { ad_placements: :ad_group } }).merge(AdGroup.where(name: 'MyAds'))
Group.where(group_type: ['Public', 'Private']).where.not(id: my_ad_groups)
```